# How to avoid zeros to became circles in Stacked Plot?

Tags: plotting

In stacked plot example:

```
fillStyle[color_] := Directive[Darker@color, AbsoluteThickness[40], CapForm["Butt"]];

ListPlot[
 {
  {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
  , {{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.0}, {2, 0.0}}
  }
 , Filling -> {1 -> {0, fillStyle[Green]}, 2 -> {{1}, fillStyle[Yellow]}}
 , PlotLayout -> "Stacked"
 ]
```

[image]

How can I avoid zero values to became circles?

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fillStyle[color_] := 
  Directive[Darker@color, AbsoluteThickness[40], CapForm["Butt"]];
```

As a workaround, replace the zeroes with a negligibly small positive value

```
ListPlot[{
   {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}},
   {{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.0}, {3, 0.0}}} /. 
  0.0 -> 10^-3,
 Filling -> {
   1 -> {0, fillStyle[Green]},
   2 -> {{1}, fillStyle[Yellow]}},
 PlotLayout -> "Stacked",
 PlotRange -> {{0.75, 3.25}, Automatic}]
```

[image]